# Leaking shower/tub enclosure

Tags: plumbing, leak

I have an acrylic (maybe fiberglass) shower/tub enclosure.  It leaks when the shower is in use, causing a stain to appear on the ceiling of the room below. The most likely culprit appears to be that there is a gap where the tub faucet comes out from the wall, maybe 1/4'' (the faucet is not flush with the enclosure buy that amount).

Is this likely to be the cause of the problem?  If so, how could it best be repaired?   I am inclined to try silicone caulk but the gap is fairly wide and I worry that it may look bad.

Edit: yes, by "tub faucet" I mean the pipe that the water comes out of when you're filling the tub.

Comment: When you say "tub faucet", do you mean the tub spout, where the water comes out to fill up the tub?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem so I may as well answer my own question.

- The spout was detachable from the pipe (it is held on by a mechanism
  which can be loosened by a hex wrench -- the nut is on the underside
  of the spout)
- Once the spout is removed, you can caulk the gap where the pipe goes 
  through the hole in the shower enclosure, and then re-attach the 
  spout. There's no need to caulk around the spout itself.
- I was able to re-attach the spout so there was not such a wide gap
  between it and the enclosure, though that's more of a cosmetic
  improvement than anything else.

There is a video of someone doing this repair [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcBdjH4Fdik).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. If this indeed answers your question, you should choose it as the answer (even though you wrote it). Thanks!